# Why am I getting a List Index error on max() function in the below code?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list sRows with the following data -

```
[[500.0, 1.0, 25.0, 15.0], [500.0, 0.75, 30.0, 20.0], [1000.0, 2.0, 25.0, 15.0]]
```

My code is -

```
sCols = len(sRows[0])
    
for r1 in range(sCols):
        
        if r1 < 2:
            print("r1 is : " + str(r1))
            rMin.append(min(sRows[r1]))
        else:
            print("r1 is : " + str(r1))
            rMin.append(max(sRows[r1]))
```

I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range error on the last line -

```
rMin.append(max(sRows[r1]))
```

From the print statements, the r1 values I get are -

```
r1 is : 0
r1 is : 1
r1 is : 2
r1 is : 3
```

Can someone kindly help me? I have spent the entire night, trying to figure out and rechecking everything. Still keep getting it.

Comment: But `sRows` doesn't have four elements, there's no element at index `3`. There *is* a fourth element in `sRows[0]` though (as well as in `sRows[1]` and `sRows[2]`).

Comment: ```len(sRows[0])``` is just the length of the first item in that three-element list..  you're using the number of elements in the sublist ..  you should use ```len(sRows)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value for your sCols variable is 4, when you pass that value to range() function, the last number it will return is 3. The value of r1 is hence 3 in your final iteration. Your list has only three elements(3 rows) and the maximun index you can have for your sRows list is 2 not 3. Hence the error! Hope it cleared.